# Отсутствует явно задаваемый атрибут экземпляра

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте! Есть класс, у которого есть примерно такой конструктор:

```
class GameTree:
  evaled = 0 # количество просчитанных листьев
  nodes = [] # уникальные листья

  def __init__(self, players, points, cp=0, level=0, line=0):
    # cp - current player
    self.state = arr_to_state(players) # arr_to_state превращает последовательность ходов в состояние поля

    for j in GameTree.nodes: # для каждого уникального листа
      if j.state == self.state: # если состояния равны - равны и объекты
        self = deepcopy(j)        
        return

    GameTree.evaled += 1
    self.index = len(GameTree.nodes)
    GameTree.nodes.append(self) # сохраняем ссылку на себя

    #
    # ...
    #

    assert hasattr(self, 'index')
```

Задача такая: построить полный граф игры в n-мерные крестики-нолики для m игроков.
Каждый объект `GameTree` содержит состояние поля и возможные развития игры. Все уникальные (те, у которых одинаковые состояния поля) экземпляры сохраняются в `GameTree.nodes`. При этом, по задумке, у каждого объекта есть индекс, который либо задается явно, либо получается от уже просчитанного.

При попытке построить граф для двумерных крестиков-ноликов:

```
GameTree(points=[[-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [0, 1], [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]],
         players=[[[0, 0]], []], 
         cp=1})
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
File "C:\Programing\Python\V4.py", line 151, in pprint
  s += ' %'+str(i.index)
AttributeError: 'GameTree' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Помогите, пожалуйста ее решить.
Весь код (местами - довольно грязный):

```
from copy import deepcopy, copy
from time import time
from threading import Thread
from math import factorial

point_class = lambda a: a.count(0)

class slist(list):
  def without(self, x):
    b = self[:]
    b.remove(x)
    return b

def to_ter_arr(i):
  if i<3:
    return [i]

  return to_ter_arr(i // 3) + [i%3]

def arr_to_num(arr):
  arr = list(map(lambda a: a+1, arr))

  ret = 0

  arr.reverse()

  for i in range(len(arr)):
    ret += (3**i)*arr[i]

  return ret

def arr_to_state(arr):
  ret = [0 for i in range(3**len(arr[0][0]))]

  for p in range(len(arr)):
    for i in arr[p]:
      ret[arr_to_num(i)] = p+1

  return ret

def gen(n):
  ret = slist()

  for i in range(pow(3, n)):
    buff = to_ter_arr(i)
    buff = [0 for i in range((n-len(buff)))]+buff
    buff = list(map(lambda a: a-1, buff))
    ret.append(buff)

  return ret

def three(a, b, c):
  if a == [] or b == [] or c== []:
    return False

  for i in range(len(a)):
    s = [a[i], b[i], c[i]]
    if not s in [[1,1,1], [-1,-1,-1], [0,0,0], [1,0,-1], [-1,0,1]]:
      return False

  return True and a!=b and a!=c and b!=c

def won(pl):
  for a in pl:
    for b in pl:
      for c in pl:
        if three(a, b, c):
          return True

  return False

class GameTree:
  evaled = 0 # количество просчитанных листьев
  nodes = [] # уникальные листья

  def __init__(self, players, points, cp=0, level=0, line=0):
    self.state = arr_to_state(players) # arr_to_state превращает последовательность ходов в состояние поля

    for j in GameTree.nodes: # для каждого уникального листа
      if j.state == self.state: # если состояния равны - равны и листья 
        self = deepcopy(j)        
        return

    GameTree.evaled += 1
    self.index = len(GameTree.nodes)
    GameTree.nodes.append(self) # сохраняем ссылку на себя

    players = slist(deepcopy(players)) # slist это list, для которого
    points = slist(deepcopy(points)) # определен метод without

    if cp == len(players): 
      cp = 0

    self.children = []

    for player in players:
      if won(player):
        return

    if points == []:
      return

    me = players[cp]
    enemies = players.without(me)

    if len(me)>=2:
      for point in points:
        me_ = me + [point]

        if won(me_):
          players[cp].append(point)
          self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(point), cp+1, level=level+1))

          return

    blocked = False

    for point in points:
      for en in enemies:
        en_ = en + [point]
        if won(en_):
          buff = deepcopy(players) 
          players[cp].append(point)

          self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(point), cp+1, level=level+1))

          players = buff
          blocked = True

    if blocked:
      return

    for point in points:
      buff = deepcopy(players)
      players[cp].append(point)
      self.children.append(GameTree(players, points.without(point), cp+1, level=level+1)) 
      players = buff

    assert hasattr(self, 'index')

  def pprint(self, f):
    s = '#{} {}'.format(self.index, self.state)

    for i in self.children:
      s += ' %'+str(i.index)

    f.write(s+'\n')

  @staticmethod
  def print_result(file_name):
    f = open(file_name, 'w')

    print('len =', len(GameTree.nodes))

    for i in GameTree.nodes:
      i.pprint(f)

    f.close()



def progress():
  global aprox, game, start
  while game.is_alive():
    print('\r{} , {} s'.format(GameTree.evaled, int(time()-start)), end='')


n = int(input('N = ') or '2')
points = gen(n)

pc = int(input('Количество игроков: ') or '2')
center = slist([0 for i in range(n)])
players = slist([[center]]+[[] for i in range(pc-1)])

file_name = input('Имя файла: ')  or 'log.txt'
f = open(file_name, 'w')

show = input('Показывать прогресс (Д\Н, Д по умолчанию)') or 'д'

if show == 'H' or show == 'н':
  show = False

elif show == 'Д' or show == 'д':
  show = True

else:
  print('Ошибка!!!')
  exit(1)

print('\nCenter =', center)
print('Players =', players)
print('Points =', points)
start = time()


game = Thread(target = GameTree, kwargs = {'players': players, 'points': points.without(center), 'cp': 1, 'level': 1})
prog = Thread(target = progress)

game.start()

if show:
  prog.start()

game.join()
progress()

GameTree.print_result(file_name)

print(time()-start, 's')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глубоко вникать в эту портянку кода я сейчас не могу, но есть подозрение, что проблема здесь:

```
for j in GameTree.nodes: # для каждого уникального листа
  if j.state == self.state: # если состояния равны - равны и листья 
    self = deepcopy(j)        
    return
```

Попробуйте заменить

```
self = deepcopy(j)
```

на

```
self.__dict__ = deepcopy(j.__dict__)
```